# scroll whole page while hovering absolute div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I want to scoll the whole page even if I am not hovering the part which is longer than the screen. 
Here is the code:

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    background: #3a3a3a;
    overflow: auto;
}

body {
    background: green no-repeat center center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
}

.menu, .submenu li {
    line-height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 22px;
    background: #4096ee;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: white;
    transition: background 0.5s;
}

.submenu li { 
    //display: none;
}

.center {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 25%;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
}

#mask {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
  <div id="mask"></div>
  <div class="center">
  <div class="menu menutwo">klick</div>
        <ul class="submenu" id="sub1">
            <li>one</li>
            <li>two</li>
            <li>three</li>
            <li>four</li>
            <li>five</li>
            <li>six</li>
            <li>seven</li>
            <li>eight</li>
            <li>nine</li>
            <li>ten</li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

I want to scroll while hovering the "margin". Its a little hard to explain, just try to scroll while hovering the green side left or right.

The center-div do not have to be with 25%, it could be in px.

Comment: Hi , Can you tell me on which element hover you want to scroll.

Comment: @AnilSamal I want to have the same effect like hovering the <li> if I hover over the margin of the "center"-div

Comment: Let's update more your stylesheet to this >> body { overflow: initial; }

Comment: @lahphim I just tried that, then is the picture (in my explanation above the color green) cutted by the bottom of the window and the scrolled part is in background-color #3a3a3a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your browser can't scroll an element it hasn't rendered. The `center` div is only rendered across 25% of the screen (centered horizontally) due to `width: 25%;` and therefore you can't scroll it on the edges. You could try some JS trickery to make it work with `width: 25%;` but in reality it's probably easier to just make the list have a margin that gives it a rendered width of 25% and a true width of 100%. Consider that with a left margin of `37.5%` and a right margin of `37.5%`, the rendered content width is `25%` and it's centered/scrollable.

This works because now both the `center` div takes up the entire width of the screen. The menu just isn't rendering its content across the entire area due to the `margin-right` and `margin-left` statements. Try out "inspect element," it's pretty good at showing where the true vs the rendered boundaries of content are.

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    background: #3a3a3a;
    overflow: auto;
}

body {
    background: green no-repeat center center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
}

.menu, .submenu li {
    line-height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 22px;
    background: #4096ee;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left: 37.5%;
    margin-right: 37.5%;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: white;
    transition: background 0.5s;
}

.submenu li { 
    //display: none;
}

.center {
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
}

#mask {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
  <div id="mask"></div>
  <div class="center">
  <div class="menu menutwo">klick</div>
        <ul class="submenu" id="sub1">
            <li>one</li>
            <li>two</li>
            <li>three</li>
            <li>four</li>
            <li>five</li>
            <li>six</li>
            <li>seven</li>
            <li>eight</li>
            <li>nine</li>
            <li>ten</li>
        </ul>
</div>
```